# XML Serialization in Unity - Have an array hold different arrayitems?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization, monodevelop

So I'm working on my game in Unity, and I encountered a problem regarding XML. I've setup a system thanks to a tutorial that allows me to create items by reading their data from an XML database. But there is one problem. I want to set up my XML file to be read as follows:

```
        <resistance>
            <physical>
                <phy>60.0</phy>
            </physical>

            <air>
                <air>50.0</air>
            </air>
        </resistance>
```

However, I have not found a way to set the  as the root to check the data in.

The format of the XML file is as follows:

```
    <Item>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>Helmet</name>
        <resistance>
            <physical>
                <phy>60.0</phy>
            </physical>

            <air>
                <air>50.5</air>
            </air>
        </resistance>
    </Item>
```

[XmlArray("resistance"), XmlArrayItem("physical")] only reads the  part. I've also tried writing everything as follows:

```
[XmlArray("resistance"), XmlArrayItem("physical"), XmlArrayItem("phy")]
public float[] phyres;
[XmlArray("air"), XmlArrayItem("air")]
public float[] airres;
```

But the XML file then got messy, although the data was read and I got the correct resistances, what followed after  was not read, as if resistance became the new permament root of the XML file.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: In other words, I want to have a subroot in my the  child, and hold a few different arrays there.

Edit:Edit: Thank you jdweng, this ended up more simple to write:

```
[XmlElement("resistance"), XmlArrayItem("physical")]
public float[] phyres;
[XmlElement("air")]
public float[] airres;
```

But I still get the same issue. The root/namespace is set to , and everything is read from that namespace afterwards. Not even the  after  affects it.

Comment: Change XmlArray to XmlElement.  XmlElement will work with arrays and eliminate one level of unnecessary tags.

Comment: @jdweng Seems like I get the same result as the last snippet of code. The root changes to that element and every elements after that are searched for in <resistance></resistance>. How would I go about to restoring the root back to <Item></Item> after reading data from the resistance element?

Comment: You have to add the resistance to the item either using XML(s) or in your classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read it, your requirement is a `resistance` element that contains an a `physical` and an `air` element.  This:

```
[XmlElement("resistance"), XmlArrayItem("physical")]
public float[] phyres;
[XmlElement("air")]
public float[] airers;
```

Doesn't represent that.  It implies a `resistance` element containing multiple `physical` elements *followed by* an `air` element.

Here is a class structure that mirrors your XML:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("resistance")]
    public Resistance Resistance { get; set; }
}

public class Resistance
{
    [XmlArray("physical")]
    [XmlArrayItem("phy")]
    public float[] Phyres { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("air")]
    [XmlArrayItem("air")]
    public float[] Air { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I've thought about this method but was hesitant to try it. Even tho I don't require this anymore, this will be very useful in the future. Thank you!